# How to replace all values in a dataframe with its Log after a check for NaN

Tags: r

I have a doubt in how to **replace all the values in a dataframe** with its **log value** if the log value passes the **!is.NaN/ is.finite** check.

I tried this:

```
abc[] <- lapply(abc, function(x){ 
  x[is.finite(log10(x))] <- log10(x)

})
```

where abc is:

```
a = c(0, 3, 5) 
b = c(0, 3, 5) 
c = c(2, 3, 5) 
abc <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

But I get the below error:

> In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NaNs produced

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That is because you are still replacing them with NaNs produced by `log10(x)`. You are literally replacing the NaNs with NaNs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed out in a comment, you are still computing the log also of the values, where it won't give finite results. You need to limit the elements of x to those where the log is finite also on the right hand side:

```
abc[] <- lapply(abc, function(x){
  finite <- is.finite(log10(x))
  x[finite] <- log10(x[finite])
  return(x)
})
```

As you can see, I use the vector `finite` on both sides of the equation. On the right hand side, this ensures that the log is only taken of the values,where this makes sense. On the left hand side, this makes sure that the results of the logs are stored at the correct position inside `x`.

It is important to return `x` in its entirety at the end, otherwise you would, e.g., return just to elements for column `a`, which leads to an error.